# Create table as select percentage subquery in Impala DB

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, count, impala

I'm newbie of Impala, i need to create table with select resultset, also, this sql is run in Java using JDBC, see my below query:

```
create table if not exists my_temp_table as select 
41 as rule_id,49 as record_id,
(select count(1) as val from dirty_table where msg regexp '^[1]([3-9])[0-9]{9}$' )/(select count(1) from dirty_table);
```

I need to create table `my_temp_table` and insert data into this table, this is one SQL that i need to run. But it runs failed and gives errer as below:

```
[HY000][500051] [Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:ParseException: Syntax error
```

After checking, i know Impala doesn't support `SELECT` clause subquery, we can only use subquery
in `FROM` or `WHERE` clause, see Impala docs: https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_subqueries.html.

So for this question how can i do to solve this problem.

My thought:

1. update sql to let it execute, I tried `WITH` like below sql, it works but can't be used in
   `CREATE TABLE ... AS ...`.

```
    WITH q1 AS (
      select count(1) as val from dirty_table where msg regexp '^[1]([3-9])[0-9]{9}$'
    ),
    q2 AS (
      select count(1) val2 from dirty_table
    )
    SELECT 100 * q1.val / q2.val2  result
    FROM q1, q2
```

2. or, is there any statement like `BEGIN ... END` in MySQL or Oracle, then i can run this sql separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your examples, I would try these approaches that, I believe, could work fine.
I checked the solution with Impala

```sql
CREATE TABLE dirty_table (
 id INT,
 msg STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED  BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;


[localhost.localdomain:21000] > SELECT * FROM dirty_table;
Query: SELECT * FROM dirty_table
Query submitted at: 2020-07-28 17:05:24 (Coordinator: http://localhost.localdomain:25000)
Query progress can be monitored at: http://localhost.localdomain:25000/query_plan?query_id=5441d6a46ce61e7b:8e49432600000000
+----+-------------+
| id | msg         |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | 13321512121 |
| 2  | 13121212121 |
| 3  | 03121212121 |
| 4  | 13321512121 |
| 5  | 13121212121 |
| 6  | 03121212121 |
| 7  | 13121212121 |
+----+-------------+
Fetched 7 row(s) in 0.14s
```

First example

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table AS
SELECT 41 AS rule_id, 49 AS record_id, val1 / val2 AS result
FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) AS val1 FROM dirty_table WHERE msg regexp '^[1]([3-9])[0-9]{9}$' ) a,
     (SELECT COUNT(1) AS val2 FROM dirty_table) b;

[localhost.localdomain:21000] > CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table AS
                              > SELECT 41 AS rule_id, 49 AS record_id, val1 / val2 AS result
                              > FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) AS val1 FROM dirty_table WHERE msg regexp '^[1]([3-9])[0-9]{9}$' ) a,
                              >      (SELECT COUNT(1) AS val2 FROM dirty_table) b;
Query: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table AS
SELECT 41 AS rule_id, 49 AS record_id, val1 / val2 AS result
FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) AS val1 FROM dirty_table WHERE msg regexp '^[1]([3-9])[0-9]{9}$' ) a,
     (SELECT COUNT(1) AS val2 FROM dirty_table) b
+-------------------+
| summary           |
+-------------------+
| Inserted 0 row(s) |
+-------------------+
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.21s

[localhost.localdomain:21000] > invalidate metadata;

[localhost.localdomain:21000] > SELECT * FROM my_temp_table;
Query: select * from my_temp_table
Query submitted at: 2020-07-28 17:03:44 (Coordinator: http://localhost.localdomain:25000)
Query progress can be monitored at: http://localhost.localdomain:25000/query_plan?query_id=47370bf793a09b:29c4dfa000000000
+---------+-----------+--------------------+
| rule_id | record_id | result             |
+---------+-----------+--------------------+
| 41      | 49        | 0.7142857142857143 |
+---------+-----------+--------------------+
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.13s
```

Second example

```sql
DROP TABLE my_temp_table;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table AS 
SELECT result FROM
    (WITH q1 AS (
      SELECT COUNT(1) AS val FROM dirty_table WHERE msg regexp '^[1]([3-9])[0-9]{9}$'
    ),
    q2 AS (
      SELECT COUNT(1) val2 FROM dirty_table
    )
    SELECT 100 * q1.val / q2.val2 AS result
    FROM q1, q2) t;

[localhost.localdomain:21000] > CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table AS 
                              > SELECT result FROM
                              >     (WITH q1 AS (
                              >       SELECT COUNT(1) AS val FROM dirty_table WHERE msg regexp '^[1]([3-9])[0-9]{9}$'
                              >     ),
                              >     q2 AS (
                              >       SELECT COUNT(1) val2 FROM dirty_table
                              >     )
                              >     SELECT 100 * q1.val / q2.val2 AS result
                              >     FROM q1, q2) t;
Query: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table AS
SELECT result FROM
    (WITH q1 AS (
      SELECT COUNT(1) AS val FROM dirty_table WHERE msg regexp '^[1]([3-9])[0-9]{9}$'
    ),
    q2 AS (
      SELECT COUNT(1) val2 FROM dirty_table
    )
    SELECT 100 * q1.val / q2.val2 AS result
    FROM q1, q2) t
+-------------------+
| summary           |
+-------------------+
| Inserted 1 row(s) |
+-------------------+
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.40s

[localhost.localdomain:21000] > invalidate metadata;

[localhost.localdomain:21000] > SELECT * FROM my_temp_table;
Query: SELECT * FROM my_temp_table
Query submitted at: 2020-07-28 17:08:17 (Coordinator: http://localhost.localdomain:25000)
Query progress can be monitored at: http://localhost.localdomain:25000/query_plan?query_id=3447684ef59d0c4:f70779200000000
+-------------------+
| result            |
+-------------------+
| 71.42857142857143 |
+-------------------+
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.74s
```

Comment: Hi @Chema, same like others answer, these two SQL only work in `SELECT` clause, after `CREATE TABLE` added, SQL couldn't work.

Comment: Add exception log(both two got same error):

`[HY000][500051] [Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:ParseException: Syntax error in line 1: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table AS ^ Encountered: EOF Expected: SELECT, VALUES, W ...`

Comment: Hi @KD Final, I changed the solution, please check now.

Comment: Hi @KD Final, I checked the solution with `Cloudera` distribution and `Impala` and it is working fine. I changed the post with a step by step solution. Maybe you are facing other issues. Regards.

Comment: This general approach is the right one - put the subqueries in the FROM clause and then reference them in the select list.

In the upcoming Impala 4.0 (and other Cloudera releases of Impala) we do have support for select list subqueries. Internally they get rewritten into queries into queries exactly like this.

Comment: Sorry for late response, @Chema, your sql was worked, i run it failed in DB GUI tool (datagrip) previously, but few days later, i found i can run is in impala shell. So i rerun in datagrip and found the reason why it failed, reason is i formatted this sql in datagrip and then there will contains line break which seems not allowed in Impala, after i removed line break and it worked.

Comment: As @TimArmstrong said, Impala 4.0 will support select subqueries, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I think a conditional average can do what you want simply and efficiently, with a single table scan:

```
select avg(case when msg regexp '^[1]([3-9])[0-9]{9}$' then 100.0 else 0 end) result
from dirty_table
```

You can turn this to a `create table` statement:

```
create table my_temp_table as
select avg(case when msg regexp '^[1]([3-9])[0-9]{9}$' then 100.0 else 0 end) result
from dirty_table
```

Comment: Hi @GMB,  test your SQL, the first `SELECT` clause worked, but the second one `CREATE TABLE` counldn't work.

There are so many restrictions in `Cloudera Impala` and no details  in it official docs.

Comment: Add exception log:

`[HY000][500051] [Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:ParseException: Syntax error in line 1: create table if not exists my_temp_table as ^ Encountered: EOF Expected: SELECT, VALUES, W ...`

Comment: @KDFinal: looks like Impala does not support `if not exists` in `create table`... I changed the query.

Comment: i test in Impala using `if not exists ` and it works, i use this simple sql `create table if not exists my_temp_table as select * from dirty_table;`, but when there are subquery in `SELECT` clause, then it failed.